# Angular2 Conditionally Escape HTML

Tags: angular

I'm building a blog on Angular2 that loads content from a Wordpress.com blog, http://forrestswork.com, and running into trouble with HTML escaping.

The innerHtml directive works great, but the html_sanitizer is removing all of the escaping, including code samples, so my component code examples are not rendering properly.

```html
<section class="content" [innerHtml]="post.content"></section>
```

Is there a way to force angular to ignore blocks of content when it escapes HTML?

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates with what content the sanitizer is causing issues? You could provide your own sanitizer implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DomSanitizer` service to escape some HTML/url/etc.

[According to the docs:](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#bypass-security-apis)

> You can mark a value as trusted by injecting DomSanitizer and calling one of the following methods:
>
> - `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`
> - `bypassSecurityTrustScript`
> - `bypassSecurityTrustStyle`
> - `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`
> - `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`

so you can escape your html like this :

```js
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  let dangerousHtml = '<script>alert("hello")</script>';
  this.trustedHtml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(dangerousHtml);
```

and in you template :

```html
<section class="content" [innerHtml]="trustedHtml"></section>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally without writing a custom sanitizer function? I would like to escape all HTML within <pre> tags, and accept everything else as safe HTML.